# Find naturals that are sum of numbers with the same digits in inverse order

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, integers

In a test I've found the following exercise:

> We say $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is **reflexive** if is the sum of two naturals $x$ and $y$ such that $y$ has the same digits of $x$ witten in the inverse order (if $x=123$ then $y$ is $321$). Find all the reflexive natural numbers.

Now, I've tried to describe them using numbers of the form $10\dots 01$ but I assume there is a more elegant characterization of reflexive numbers.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Is $11=10+01$ reflexive?

Comment: I've to be honest: by the text of exercise it is not very clear. Well, I think 11  is reflexive and so you can assume $n$ is reflexive in this kind of cases.

Comment: Let $x=\overline{a_1a_2\ldots a_m}$, $y=\overline{a_m a_{m-1}\ldots a_1}$. Then $$x+y=(10^m+1)a_1+(10^{m-1}+10^1)a_2+...=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{\frac{m+1}2}\rfloor}({10}^k+{10}^{m-k})a_k$$